# Determine the value of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{j}{n^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits

Taken from W.J Kaczor, *Problem in mathematical analysis,* page 28.

Determine the value:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{j}{n^3}.$$

My attempt: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{j}{n^3}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{j=1}^{i}j$$

After that, I'm not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming is a positive integer, the well known formulas 
$$\sum_{k=1}^mk=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\sum_{k=1}^mk^2=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6},$$ 
yield with some basic algebra
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{j}{n^3}
&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{j=1}^ij=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i+1)}{2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni+\frac{1}{2n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\\
&=&\frac{1}{2n^3}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{1}{2n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
&=&\frac{2n^3+6n^2+3n}{12n^3}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence the limit is
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{j}{n^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: thanks  a lots @servaes

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula for $\sum_{j=1}^i j$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cesaro-Stolz the desired limit is equal to the limit of $$\frac{1}{n^3-(n-1)^3}\sum_{j=1}^{n}j$$ and this is same as the limit of $$\frac{1}{3n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}j$$ Applying Cesaro-Stolz again we see that the desired limit is equal to the limit of $$\frac{n}{3(n^2-(n-1)^2)}$$ which is clearly $1/6$ and we are done.